# PHP: "Footer function"?

Tags: php

I have a project. It has a good number of PHP files. Each of these files includes a standard header. They don't include a standard footer.

Now I want to do something just before the end of every page. I can go through each page and add the footer code, but I was wondering if there is an easier way (and I think I've seen something like it before, though I might be mistaken).

**Is there a way to set a "hook" or "trigger" function that will be executed at the end of a page, from the included header PHP script? I'm thinking of something like [set_error_handler](http://php.net/set_error_handler) but to handle a page close event. Or like C's [atexit](http://www.cprogramming.com/fod/atexit.html) function.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ah, I found the function I was looking for, FINALLY. Believe me, I've been searching for this for a while, and just happened upon it!

[register_shutdown_function](http://php.net/register_shutdown_function)— Register a function for execution on shutdown

Comment: I go with this solution. A shutdown function is executed, even if you terminate your script with `exit` or `die`. The `auto_append_file` will not be executed in this case. This if a very important difference to consider.

Answer (score 2):

The `auto_append_file` setting in php.ini will `require` a file at the end of every PHP page:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-append-file

Note this applies site-wide to EVERY PHP file.

Comment: Ah, this is one folder of an even larger website though, so that wouldn't work.

Comment: Yes it will - you can set it in an .htaccess file to apply to that folder and below

Comment: Oh, cool! register_shutdown_function did what I needed but I'll definitely keep this in mind!

Answer (score 0):

I think you're thinking of auto_prepend_file and auto_append_file:

http://www.aarongloege.com/blog/web-development/php/automatically-include-files/