# Include footer page to any page in the server

Tags: php, apache

I want to Include some footer page to any page in my server without calling the file from the pages.

I know that there is a way to do that with apache or something like that, but I have no idea how to do that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: "Footer function"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2860932/php-footer-function) - This questions and answers should give you some insights. If you're more concerned how to do that apache only w/o any PHP, you should write that in your question because it's done differently.

Answer (score 2):

In your `.htaccess`, you can do it with:

```
php_value auto_append_file 'footer.php'
```

The file must exist in PHP's `include_path`. [See the documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-append-file) for slightly more information.

The `auto_append_file` directive can also be set in php.ini.

Comment: I'm getting: "Internal Server Error 500" how can I fix it?

Comment: @LikLik Look in your Apache error_log to see what the actual error is.

Comment: I'm sorry my bad :)I didn't read your second line "The file must exist in PHP's include_path"

Answer (score 2):

I suggest going with `register_shutdown_function()` instead of `auto_append_file`, because the  `auto_append_file` is not executed if the main script is terminated with `exit`. This is a very important difference between both options.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to DerVO's answer...

It may be possible (but it's not trivial) to force a div included earlier in the output stream to be rendered at the [bottom of the page using CSS](http://www.webmasterworld.com/css/3248614.htm). Alternatively you could output the content in a non-displayed div and use javascript to append a copy of its innerHTML to the inner html of the last element in the body.